# Docker container doesn't start after reboot with enabling systemd script

Tags: docker, systemd, reboot, docker-container

I have the following systemd script:

```
[Unit]
Description=Hub docker container
After=docker.service

[Service]
User=root
ExecStart=/home/hub/hub.sh
ExecStop=/bin/docker stop hub
ExecStopPost=/bin/docker rm hub

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Running the command: **systemctl start/stop hub** works fine. I also created the symlink by using **systemctl enable hub**. Why doesn't my service start up after I reboot the entire laptop? I followed the docker guide so that Docker starts up on reboot, but for some reason my container doesn't start up. Am I missing a field in my script?

The command I am using my ExecStart, "/home/hub/hub.sh" script is:

```
docker run --net=host --restart=always --name hub -t hub
```

After reboot I get the following when I type systemctl status hub:

```
● hub.service - Hub docker container
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/hub.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to start container after reboot you need to add this property: `--restart=always` to your container start script. For example:
`docker run -d -p 80:5000 --restart=always image_name`

Comment: I added the restart flag but it still isn't working, this is the docker command I am using in my "hub.sh" script: docker run --net=host --restart=always --name hub -t hub

Comment: Nevermind, it worked. Turns out I forgot to enable the service after I changed the wantedby to multi-user. Thanks so much!

Comment: Actually I prefer to use `--restart unless-stopped`

Comment: This answer tells the user to use Docker's restart management but it looks like the OP wants to use systemd. The [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/#use-a-process-manager) say, "Do not try to combine Docker restart policies with host-level process managers, because this creates conflicts."

Answer (score 12):

In my case, I already had the containers set to `restart=always` (btw you can inspect a container's restart policy with `docker inspect -f "{{ .HostConfig.RestartPolicy.Name }}" <container>` and/or change it with `docker update --restart=always <container>`) but the containers still were not starting up until I ran a command like `docker ps`.

It turns out that the **socket** was enabled in systemd, but the **service** itself was disabled and so wouldn't start until a command was issued against it.

Inspecting via `systemctl status docker.socket` and `systemctl status docker.service` verified this:

```
root@poke:~# systemctl status docker.socket
● docker.socket - Docker Socket for the API
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.socket; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-07-30 18:28:38 EDT; 18h ago
   Listen: /var/run/docker.sock (Stream)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4647)
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.socket
   
root@poke:~# systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-07-31 13:19:53 EDT; 5min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 3094 (dockerd)
    Tasks: 20
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           ├─3094 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
           └─3426 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 6379 -container-ip 172.17.0.3 -container-
```

(Note the "disabled" for `docker.service`, even though it was running at the time.)

I was able to fix this by running `systemctl enable --now docker.service`:

```
root@poke:~# systemctl enable --now docker.service
Synchronizing state of docker.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable docker
```

Many thanks to [this reddit user's reply](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/es7n2u/containers_fail_to_start_on_reboot_until_i_do_a/ff8f77v/) for tipping me off.