# Failed to start docker container after reboot

Tags: docker, init, reboot

I am hosting an own registry.
After rebooting the Server my registry container is unable to start.

I used this command to start the registry

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name registry -v /var/lib/registry/:/var/lib/registry -v /root/certs:/certs -v /root/auth/:/auth -eEGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/domain.crt -e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:5000 -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/domain.key -e "REGISTRY_AUTH=htpasswd" -e "REGISTRY_AUTH=htpasswd" -e REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/auth/htpasswd -e "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM=Registry Realm" --restart always registry:2.7.1
```

After a reboot i get this message when i try "docker start registry":

> Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container with id exists: dfb0bef21bdfc8a89b59498befd37f83513e75527c0beb552e0400df2a2b7c7d: unknown
>   Error: failed to start containers: registry

Starting a new container works fine.
How can a fix, it and sould the container not start by itself because of "--restart alway"

```
docker --version
```

Docker version 18.09.6, build 481bc77

Thx for your help.

#### Update

Intesting news I have written an init script to to the job,
but the problem is exactly the same.  The container exists but isn't started.
If I try to start it, I get the error message from above.

On the boot screen in get this information.
[image]

So the docker daemon seam to be not ready.
Do you have any suggestions why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker container doesn't start after reboot with enabling systemd script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49999068/docker-container-doesnt-start-after-reboot-with-enabling-systemd-script)